# What is/was the meaning of the __loadds keyword in C compilers for x86 real mode?

Tags: c, x86, cpu-registers, real-mode

I've run into the `__loadds` keyword as a function declaration modifier in some old code for 16-bit Windows that I was looking at out of curiosity.

A [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?num=20&rlz=1C1CAFA_enCA726CA726&espv=2&q=__loadds%20keyword&oq=__loadds%20keyword&gs_l=serp.3..0i71k1l8.54395.54395.0.54450.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.uH1EX0lCCZw) did not yield anything useful, presumably because no one uses the compilers that supported that keyword anymore.  I'm guessing from its name that it had something to do with the `DS` (data segment) register and the segmented memory model of x86 real mode.

Comment: It is obsolete unless you are trying to build 16-bit Windows applications in some environments. The `__loadds` keyword is described as ___loadds

This keyword aid those programming Microsoft Windows. __loadds causes the compiler to load DS from DGROUP on entry to the function and to restore DS on exit._ . It is applied to functions as a modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The online documentation for the Digital Mars compiler](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/pointers16.html) talks about this function declaration modifier:

> **`__loadds`**
>
> This keyword aid those programming Microsoft Windows. `__loadds` causes the compiler to load `DS` from `DGROUP` on entry to the function and to restore `DS` on exit.
>
> The `-mu` compiler option applies `__loadds` to all functions.

Note that this modifier is completely obsolete, as applies only to *16-bit* Windows environments, like Windows 3.1.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please take the relevant part from the website that applies and make it part of your answer.

Comment: In lieu of a downvote, I've turned this into the answer it should have been. Please take note of Michael's advice and this example in the future when you want to refer to external resources.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance guys, I try to improve on it!